# Connecting DB2 from Node.js on Windows-platform

Tags: windows, node.js, db2

I am currently mirroring the DB2 to local MySQL-db with some jdbc-code. I would like to connect DB2 directly from Node.js app without having to query the mirror. I am running on Windows and I cannot change to Linux. It seems that work on DB2 with Node.js is yet very marginal or node-odbc is used (unixODBC bindings for node).

I found this project https://github.com/herzi/db2.js which provides DB2-bindings for Node but I cannot install it as the install fails. The package requires Node-gyp (installed this successfully) and .NET framework SDK. I set the vcbuild.exe into my PATH. After these the msbuild.exe complained about missing header files (sqlcli1.h, sqlsystm.h, sqlca.h), which I found out are part of PRO*C.

I took the header files above from here: http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/dev/php_build/include/db2/ and put them into my Node's src/ directory. Now the compiler shows multiple errors.

Are there any other options when working with Windows to connect DB2 from Node.js app than try to get the above module to work?

Anyone able to help me out here? What are the steps to get the above module installed?

Thanks!

Errors shown:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C2146 : syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SQLSTATE' [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SQLSTATE' [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Documents and Settings\tpaleniu\.node-gyp\0.8.12\src\sqlcli1.h(1501): error C2371: 'SQLTCHAR' : redefinition; different basic types [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sqlext.h(30) : see declaration of 'SQLTCHAR'

..\src\connection.cc(77): error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found 

[C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]..\src\connection.cc(80): error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

..\src\connection.cc(111): error C3861: 'bzero': identifier not found [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

..\src\connection.cc(208): error C3861: 'bzero': identifier not found [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

..\src\connection.cc(547): error C2057: expected constant expression [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

..\src\connection.cc(547): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]

..\src\connection.cc(547): error C2133: 'argv' : unknown size [C:\IS\node\node_modules\db2\build\db2.vcxproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that node-odbc currently is currently meant only for use with unixODBC. But Daniel VerWeire is currently working on [supporting node-odbc on Windows](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc/issues/31). I guess you need to wait a little while.

Praveen will have a post on it [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/pd/entry/using_ibm_db2_from_node_js34?lang=en_us) as soon as it is available