# How to connect to DB2 SQL database with node JS?

Tags: node.js, db2

For linux, one can use the API page found [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db), and connecting is straight forward. For OS X, one will run into the error when trying to connect to an existing DB2 database:

```
{ [Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004 ] error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR', message: '[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\n', state: 'HY000' }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest answer on [this issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/34) gives you the answer:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/.../<project_folder>/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver/lib/icc
node app.js
```

You have to do this every time you enter the shell, so you may as well put this in your .profile or .bash_profile.